# Mercury Elite Pro Dual mini only getting 250MB/s read and write

Tags: external-disk

I have a Mercury Elite Pro Dual mini with dual 4TB drives in hardware RAID0 (the enclosure has a raid switcher).

I have formatted the drive to APFS.

I am connecting to a 2016 MBP w/TB using the supplied Thunderbolt 3 cable.

Could anyone tell me why I would only be getting MAX 250 MB/s read AND write, and how I could possibly remedy it.

The enclosure advertises up to 860MB/s

Enclosure: https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/external-drives/owc-mercury-elite-pro-dual/mini

[image: Disk Speed Test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are HDDs not SSDs inside? 250 MB/sec is good speed for a RAID 0 on two hard disk drives. The 860 MB number is probably calculated using maximum speeds reading data that is already in the hard drive's disk cache. Meaning you'll his that number for a millisecond, but once you start reading from the platter, you're limited to the maximum read speed of a physical disk.... times two.

I've had good lock with Mediasonic USB3 drive towers. I have their 8 bay but they make 4 bay too. four 2 TB drives in a RAID 0 (hardware or software) should give you much faster throughput.

Comment: I am not using SSD. I see now the macsales.com link I supplied is quoting for SSD, not HDD. The quote for HDD is: "Sustained speeds up to 291MB/s / 3 Year OWC Limited Warranty"